# How to avoid if constuct in function that returns a templated object, but still keep it inline

Tags: c++, inline, copy-constructor

I am trying to keep the code as simple as possible, so please don't mind it not making any sense.
Say I have a function that creates concrete objects of a templated class depending of a parameter :

```
concrete_object create(int val, int kind)
    {
        switch (kind)
        {
        case constant_one_k : 
            return concrete_object(template_implementation1_t(), val);
            break;
        case constant_two_k:
            return concrete_object(template_implementation2_t(), val);
            break;
        default:
            throw;

        }
    }
```

`create` will be called many many times, and always with the same kind of template spetialization, so i would like to avoid having an if evaluated every time I call `create`. However, every solution that I try also calls copy/move constructors when returning the value, which is not acceptable, since important code is in the destructors and it cannot be called "more times than expected".
To be clear:
If i invoke this as `auto c = create(value, constant_one_k)` only a constructor and destructor for c are called, I am guessing this is because of RVO, so all copy and move constructors are omitted. That's exactly what i am looking for.

Can this be done without the swich being executed every time?

EDIT:
The conrete type of object returned depends on an input parameter (e.g. given by the user at runtime), so in one run of the program the same type of object will always be returned. I would like to know if it is possible to avoid the "switch" overhead, no matter how small it may be. 
I tried to make the `create` method a template method, and then defining a function pointer that would be set to the concrete specialization of the `create` method, but that invokes a copy constructor when the element is returned from the method, so it's not acceptable.

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions here, but I'm particularly confused about two points: (1) what do you mean "always with the same kind of template spetialization"? Are you saying this switch statement *always* follows the same code path? If so, why is the other branch even there?

Comment: (2) what does the switch statement have to do with whether your return statement invokes a copy constructor?

Comment: @KyleStrand: It has a lot to do with _which_ copy constructor is invoked. Though I suspect the OP didn't intend to slice.

Comment: `switch` isn't a _loop_.

Comment: Perfomance cost of this switch is low, if usually follows the same code path, cpu branch prediction should optimize aswell

Comment: BTW please do not take the close-votes as an indication that the question isn't welcome--it just needs a decent amount of clarification. Even if the question does get closed, it will still be visible, and can be reopened if you clarify it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Do you mean slicing in the inheritance sense? I'm not familiar with any other meaning in C++, but I also don't see any inheritance here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ...also I'm not familiar with how returning from a `switch` can affect slicing.

Comment: @KyleStrand: It is impossible to "return from a `switch`", but look at the return type of the _function_. re inheritance you could be right - I extrapolated from what I saw but without knowing what `concrete_object` is...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant return (from a function) from inside of a `switch` statement,  as shown in the code above. This is of course in contrast to `break`ing out of the `switch` and `return`ing later. I still don't quite grasp what you're saying--both `return` statements and the function signature specify the same type, `concrete_object`, and not any derived or base types.

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, agreed.

Comment: OP -- just realized another oddity: you probably don't mean that the function must be "inline", which is not necessary for avoiding extraneous copy-constructors.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to answer some questions. I am not skilled in c++ enough to know if copy-constructor are not called because the method is made inline, or because of RVO, I just see that no copy-contr is being called in the code above. I need to keep it that way, but if possible avoid evaluating the type of object to be returned in every call of the create. see edit, I hope it's a bit clearer now.